# Equivalent of WHERE IN () SQL in Apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I was wondering if there is any equivalent of `where in (select col1 from tbl where col = col2)` in Apache pig. In other words, how can I find out if relation A is a subset of relation B or the common tuples between relation A and B.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is equivalent to inner joins.
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#JOIN+%28inner%29
I would refer where in as sugar syntax for the join. For example in oracle you can put set of constants as well a sub query there.